# file upload works with only one specified extension but not more than one

Tags: files

I can't figure out what is wrong with this code for file uploads. I am trying to specify multiple extensions for the file upload - it works with a single extension, but if I specify more, it fails and only accepts the last item in the list, even though the error message appears to be self-contradicting. If no extensions are specified the system default list works correctly, but I need to add some extensions.

I am enclosing the minimal code, since after trying everything, modifying this code was the only difference between success and failure:

This works (regardless of the extension)

```
$file = file_save_upload('sequencefile', 
    array(
             'file_validate_extensions' => array('seq')));
```

This fails on 'jpg', but works on 'seq'; moving jpg to the end of the list works for jpg, but then fails for the others.

```
$file = file_save_upload('sequencefile', 
     array(
             'file_validate_extensions' => array('jpg, jpeg, png, gif, txt, doc, docx, ab1, seq')));
```

The error message on a jpg file is as follows, even though jpg is clearly in the list:

```
"The specified file mbpdpermissionsP2.jpg could not be uploaded. Only files with the following extensions are allowed: jpg, jpeg, png, gif, txt, doc, docx, ab1, seq."
```

What am I missing? it should be very simple and yet I can't get it to work.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a comma separation, separate extensions just with space

```
'file_validate_extensions' => array('jpg jpeg png gif txt doc docx ab1 seq')));
```

Comment: To better explain, $validators is an array keyed by callback functions. Thus the member $validators['file_validate_extensions'][0] will be passed to the function [file_validate_extensions( &$file, $extensions](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_validate_extensions/7) which is expecting: **$extensions: A string with a space separated list of allowed extensions.** Always check the API.

Comment: Thank you so very much! I knew a different pair of eyes would have seen it